# Leaflet for R: How to change default CSS cluster classes

Tags: css, r, shiny, leaflet, rstudio

How do I change the default CSS classes which define cluster objects from within the Leaflet for R interface? For example, if I wanted to remove the opacity from the .marker-cluster-small class, how could I do this from within R?

Here is the CSS which creates the cluster classes: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/64a2d5711521e56cac8ab863fb658beda5690600/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js

For example, I want to remove the opacity from the clusters, e.g.

```
.marker-cluster-small {
    background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 1.0);
    }
.marker-cluster-small div {
    background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 1.0);
    }
```

Is there a way to do this from within iconCreateFunction ?

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount(); 
    var c = ' marker-cluster-';  
    if (childCount < 100) {  
      c += 'large';  
    } else if (childCount < 1000) {  
      c += 'medium';  
    } else { 
      c += 'small';  
    }    
    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });

  }"))
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can maybe try to add inline CSS to the different markers in the function that creates the icons, for ex:

```
clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount();  
    if (childCount < 100) {  
      c = 'rgba(181, 226, 140, 1.0);'
    } else if (childCount < 1000) {  
      c = 'rgba(240, 194, 12, 1);'  
    } else { 
      c = 'rgba(241, 128, 23, 1);'  
    }    
    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div style=\"background-color:'+c+'\"><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster', iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });

  }")
```

If you are using `shiny`, you can also change the `iconCreateFunction` to assign a different class to each marker, and add `tags$style` in the header to set the CSS for these classes. Here's an example:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
  .marker-custom-small {
  background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 1);
    }
.marker-customr-small div {
    background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 1);
    }

.marker-custom-medium {
    background-color: rgba(241, 211, 87, 1);
    }
.marker-custom-medium div {
    background-color: rgba(240, 194, 12, 1);
    }

.marker-custom-large {
    background-color: rgba(253, 156, 115, 1);
    }
.marker-custom-large div {
    background-color: rgba(241, 128, 23, 1);
    }"))),
  leafletOutput("mymap"))

server<-function(input, output, session) {
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers(
      clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS("function (cluster) {    
    var childCount = cluster.getChildCount(); 
    var c = ' marker-custom-';  
    if (childCount < 100) {  
      c += 'large';  
    } else if (childCount < 1000) {  
      c += 'medium';  
    } else { 
      c += 'small';  
    }    
    return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });

  }"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Couldn't figure out how to have custom CSS in the `leaflet` outside of a `shiny` app.

Comment: Interesting, both are great workarounds. This, plus the ability to edit the CSS in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/leaflet/htmlwidgets/plugins/Leaflet.markercluster is enough to get around the issue, although it seems like at this point it's almost easier to just use regular leaflet JS!

Comment: do you know, how to avoid to show the weird polygons on hover?

Comment: @NicE, in the CSS definition you have misspelled the name of the class: `.marker-customr-small` should be without `r` -- `.marker-custom-small`

Comment: @Ferroao you need to set `showCoverageOnHover` to `FALSE` in `addMarkers()`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to manually edit the default CSS file that comes with leaflet.R. I ran .libPaths() to find my library path, then did a grep search of the leaflet directory until I found Leaflet.markercluster here:

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/leaflet/htmlwidgets/plugins/Leaflet.markercluster

from there, I opened the MarkerCluster.Defaults.css file and edited the CSS,

```
.marker-cluster-small {
    background-color: rgba(181, 226, 140, 1.0);
    }
.marker-cluster-small div {
    background-color: rgba(110, 204, 57, 1.0);
    }
```

From here it would also be easy to define custom cluster classes. However, I'd like to avoid messing with the stability of the package if possible, and it would be great to be able to define the appropriate CSS on the fly form within leaflet.R or htmlwidgets.R