# How can I make my two R leaflet maps synchronise with each other?

Tags: r, google-maps, openstreetmap, r-mapview, r-leaflet

I have had some nice success implementing `Leaflet` package in R for some data.

I have also managed to put two maps side by side as a lattice, and as a sync.

I have two issues:

**1) Sync...does not sync the maps at all**

I am using `Mapview` and `Raster` to attempt sync but the two maps side by side do not zoom in/out together.

See the code below:

```
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
library(mapview)
library(raster)
library(magrittr)
UK <- ggmap::geocode("United Kingdom")

#FILE1 <- read.csv("DATASET1.csv")
#FILE2 <- read.csv("DATASET2.csv")
FILE1 <- data.frame('lat' = c(51.31, 51.52, 51.53), 'lon' = c(0.06, 0.11, 0.09))
FILE2 <- data.frame('lat' = c(52.20, 52.25, 52.21), 'lon' = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12))

map1 <- leaflet(FILE1)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

map2 <- leaflet(FILE2)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

sync(map1,map2)
```

I am sure I am missing something simple here but hopefully someone can help me in seeing that :)

**2) Ideally I want one leaflet map to overlap the other one**

I want to differentiate them by using different markets for each map. I have attempted to research this on the internet and through reading the manuals for leaflet but to no success

any guidance greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the version of mapview and leaflet? Recently there is an update in leaflet, which may affect mapview sync function. This has been fixed in the development version of mapview. Try `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/m‌​apview@develop")` to install the development version. See my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42640120/sync-function-in-the-r-package-only-shows-one-panel-of-map

Comment: it is saying i need to install Rtools, but when i try it says Rtools is not available

Comment: What is your version of R? Try to upgrade to 3.3.3 and download the latest Rtools at this website (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

Comment: I am using RStudio, not R itself. I have downloaded RTools just

Comment: You cant use RStudio without R,...

Comment: I have R ofcourse, but i do everything within RStudio...

Comment: Rtools is not a package. You need to download and install from here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: @TimSalabim yep downloaded !

Comment: Then `devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/m‌​‌​apview@develop")` should work

Comment: Tried that didn't work. Will try again on Monday

Comment: hi, late reply but just tried it again and it is not working

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of what's in FILE1 and FILE2? One way would be to generate some toy data a la `data.frame('lat' = c(51.1, 49.9, 51.0), 'lon' = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5))`. Another option would be to run `dput(FILE1)` and copy the output here.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding some toy data for the time being. Feel free to change it to something more extensive.

Comment: the file literally just contain latitudes and longitudes, nothing else

Comment: will try your sample data out first and report back

Comment: @JanLauGe just tested it with your sample data... still is not syncing both maps ...

Comment: Yes, the sample data is mostly just to make our life easier :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1) Syncing two maps

Installing the development version solved this for me

```
# Dependencies
# If your devtools is not the latest version
# then you might have to install "units" manually
install.packages('units') 
install.packages('devtools')
library(devtools)

devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/mapview", ref = "develop")
```

The code I used:

```
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
library(mapview)
library(raster)
library(magrittr)
UK <- ggmap::geocode("United Kingdom")

#FILE1 <- read.csv("DATASET1.csv")
#FILE2 <- read.csv("DATASET2.csv")
FILE1 <- data.frame('lat' = c(51.31, 51.52, 51.53), 'lon' = c(0.06, 0.11, 0.09))
FILE2 <- data.frame('lat' = c(52.20, 52.25, 52.21), 'lon' = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12))

map1 <- leaflet(FILE1)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

map2 <- leaflet(FILE2)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addMarkers(clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions())

mapview::latticeView(map1, map2, ncol = 2, sync = list(c(1, 2)), sync.cursor = FALSE, no.initial.sync = FALSE)
# Or:
sync(map1, map2)
```

---

## 2) Overlaying two maps

You can use two separate data frames as data sources and add them to the same map separately. Change the symbol style to be able to differentiate between them.

```
map3 <- leaflet(FILE2)%>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = FILE1) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = FILE2,
                   color = '#0FF')
map3
```

If you want to do something similar for the cluster markers, there is some good documentation on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33600021/leaflet-for-r-how-to-customize-the-coloring-of-clusters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33634901/leaflet-for-r-how-to-change-default-css-cluster-classes). Based on some of the code from those posts I created a suggestion below where I use the pre-existing styles to differentiate between clusters of different types:

```
FILE1 <- data.frame('lat' = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 51.4, sd = 0.5), 
                    'lon' = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0.8, sd = 0.5))
FILE2 <- data.frame('lat' = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 53, sd = 0.5), 
                    'lon' = rnorm(n = 1000, mean = -0.5, sd = 0.5))

map3 <- leaflet(rbind(FILE1, FILE2)) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = FILE1,
    color = '#FA5',
    opacity = 1,
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction = JS("function (cluster) {    
      var childCount = cluster.getChildCount(); 
      var c = ' marker-cluster-';  
      if (childCount < 3) {  
        c += 'large';  
      } else if (childCount < 5) {  
        c += 'large';  
      } else { 
        c += 'large';  
      }    
      return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', 
      className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
  
    }"))) %>%
  addCircleMarkers(data = FILE2,
    color = '#9D7',
    opacity = 1,
    clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction = JS("function (cluster) {    
      var childCount = cluster.getChildCount(); 
      var c = ' marker-cluster-';  
      if (childCount < 3) {  
        c += 'small';  
      } else if (childCount < 5) {  
        c += 'small';  
      } else { 
        c += 'small';  
      }    
      return new L.DivIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + childCount + '</span></div>', 
      className: 'marker-cluster' + c, iconSize: new L.Point(40, 40) });
  
    }")))
```

[image: example map]

Comment: Re. rependencies, it is a bug in the newest `devtools` release, installing version 1.11.1 fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for this! just working through to make sure this works properly under all conditions. Also, attempting a simple `clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions()` is not returning a cluster for my custom icon on the second dataset

Comment: Hi I cant get the iconcreatefunction to work above... i have managed to overlay 2 datasets, and also managed to use 2 different markers... but for FILE2 i cannot get it to cluster like FILE1... FILE2 contains the customer marker i added

Comment: Could you update part 2) of your question with a reproducible example please?

Comment: Hi, sorry will have some time tomorrow to try again. Despite this, i will still accept your answer as i have achieved what i set out to, the stuff above in comments is more ancillary